# XML Work FLow Deployment in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

Hi Guyz,

I am trying to deploy the following test workflow definition in alfresco, since from 2 dayz :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process-definition xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.1" name="helloWorld">
<start-state name="start">
<transition name="" to="hello"></transition>
</start-state>
<node name="hello">
<transition name="" to="end1">
<action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
<script>
logger.log("Hello World!");
</script>
</action>
</transition>
</node>
<end-state name="end1"></end-state>
</process-definition>"
```

But when im going to deploy the above workflow definition in alfresco community 4.2 through "work-flow.jsp, it gives me following error message.

"org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowException: 03200027 Workflow Component for engine id 'jbpm' is not registered"

Please Help !

Comment: Why are you using JBPM? Activiti is the recommended Workflow engine to use

Answer (score 2):

JBPM is disabled by default!

Onine docs: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/adminconsole-workflow.html

Snippet:
set the following properties in your alfresco-global.properties.

```
system.workflow.engine.jbpm.enabled=true
system.workflow.engine.jbpm.definitions.visible=true
```

Comment: Thank You Mr:Tahir Malik. I succesfuly deployed the work flow definition after setting the configurations as you said:)